# Proof of isomorphism between sum of ordinals

Tags: set-theory, well-orders

I want to prove that the sum of two ordinals $\alpha$, $\beta$ is isomorphic to the corresponding sum $\alpha \oplus \beta$ of two well-ordered sets, where i'm using this definition of sum of two well-ordered sets: $(A,<_1),(B,<_2)$, $A \oplus B$ is $(A \ \times \{0\} \cup B \ \times \{1\},<)$ with $(a,0)<(a',0)$ iff $a <_1 a'$; $(b,1)<(b',1)$ iff $b <_2 b'$ and $(a,0)<(b,1)$ for all $a,b$. To prove the above result, should i act by transfinite induction? Or could i find an explicit bijection? For example this: $\phi: \alpha +\beta \to \alpha \oplus \beta$ where if $\gamma \in \alpha+\beta, \gamma < \alpha$ $\phi(\gamma)=(\gamma,0)$ and if $\gamma \in \alpha+\beta, \gamma \geq \alpha$ so $\gamma= \alpha + \mu$ and $\phi(\gamma)=(\mu,1)?$

Comment: Two points. First, I see that you have explicitly defined $\alpha \oplus \beta$; but you have not explicitly defined $\alpha + \beta$, including that would help to answer your question. Second, the method of "explicit bijection" is, to me, always more direct and satisfying, *if* one can make an educated guess at a formula for the appropriate bijection. But since I cannot tell how $\alpha + \beta$ is defined, it is hard to understand your formula for $\phi$, and thus hard to answer your question.

Comment: $\alpha+\beta$ is defined by transfinite recursion: 1) $\alpha+0=\alpha$; 2)$\alpha+(\beta+1)=(\alpha+\beta)+1$; 3)$\alpha+\lambda=\bigcup_{\gamma < \lambda} \alpha+\gamma$.

Comment: If you’ve already proved that if $\alpha\le\gamma\in\alpha+\beta$, then there is a $\mu\in\beta$ such that $\gamma=\alpha+\mu$, then your explicit bijection is fine. If not, proving it is going to involve about the same work as proving by induction on $\beta$ that $\alpha+\beta$ is order-isomorphic to $\alpha\oplus\beta$.

Comment: No. I thought I could get away with subtraction (left) between ordinals to find $\mu$.

Comment: Using subtraction is OK if and only if it has been proved that subtraction is well-defined (which amounts to pretty much the same as what @BrianM.Scott said).